Using python OpenCV and ZED 2 for disparity mapping without ZED SDK
I want to use the ZED 2 to make a disparity map using Opencv2 in python. Because it is a school assignment I need to implement the algorithm myself, and I can't use the ZED SDK. I can use opencv library and functions such as cv2.StereoBM_create() stereo.compute(imgL_gray, imgR_gray).
I followed a few online tutorials like Turtorial and these work for the images they provide, but they do not work with my images from the ZED2.
I used the ZED 2.
Here is the image I got from the ZED converted to png.
Original Image


The best end result I got is this. As you can see, it has some form of depth, but it is definitely not a nice disparity map.
Disparity map
This is the code I used. I tried a lot of them but none got better results than this. I would love some help on how to improve these results. I also tried a lot of different parameters already.
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Load the image in grayscale
image = cv2.imread('TestImage4.png', 0)

# Split the image into left and right halves
left_right_image = np.split(image, 2, axis=1)

# Display the left and right images
cv2.imshow("Left Image", left_right_image[0])
cv2.imshow("Right Image", left_right_image[1])
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Parameters for the StereoSGBM algorithm
block_size = 11
min_disp = 0
max_disp = 255
num_disp = max_disp - min_disp
uniquenessRatio = 5
speckleWindowSize = 200
speckleRange = 2
disp12MaxDiff = 0

# Create the StereoSGBM object
stereo = cv2.StereoSGBM_create(
    minDisparity=min_disp,
    numDisparities=num_disp,
    blockSize=block_size,
    uniquenessRatio=uniquenessRatio,
    speckleWindowSize=speckleWindowSize,
    speckleRange=speckleRange,
    disp12MaxDiff=disp12MaxDiff,
    P1=8 * 3 * block_size ** 2,
    P2=32 * 3 * block_size ** 2,
    mode=cv2.STEREO_SGBM_MODE_SGBM
)

# Compute the disparity map
disparity = stereo.compute(left_right_image[0], left_right_image[1])

# Normalize the disparity map for displaying
disparity = cv2.normalize(disparity, disparity, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
disparity = np.uint8(disparity)

# Resize the disparity map for better viewing
disparity_resized = cv2.resize(disparity, (disparity.shape[1] // 2, disparity.shape[0] // 2))

# Display the disparity map
cv2.imshow("Disparity", disparity_resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


the images haven't been rectified. disparity calculation requires rectified images. please browse OpenCV's tutorials. better yet, get a book on the subject matter. code isn't something you "find on the internet" and "try".

Sadly it still gives the same type of input images, with a lot of flakes instead of a smooth image

"still"? did you do anything differently from 4 hours ago?

I would continue my research (1.) trying different images with different objects, complexity, lighting conditions etc. and (2.) with a GUI that helps you to understand the impact of different parameter settings (like https://learnopencv.com/depth-perception-using-stereo-camera-python-c/). After you have dived deeper into the matter you still can edit your question and limit it to one specific problem. Finally, if it is for school you should focus on presenting your own ideas and methodology.

different images will do nothing as long as they're not undistorted and rectified, which is a step in this pipeline that OP didn't perform so far. the blog post is a good source. the author is actually involved with OpenCV and the post's content covers at least mentions rectification (but not undistortion) and links to another article...
